# Inserting changing for-loop variable into model formula

Tags: r, function, loops, variables, runtime-error

I have the following function:

```
sincos.chooser <- function(mod,min,max) {
  my.aic.sincos <- matrix(NA, ncol=2, nrow=max)
  for(k in c(min:max)) { 
    sincos.update <- update(mod, .~. + I(cos(2*pi/k*(order.ID))) + I(sin(2*pi/k*(order.ID))))
    my.aic.sincos[k,] <- c(k,AIC(sincos.update))
  }
  my.aic.sincos
}
```

But when I run the function I get the following error:

```
Error in get("k") : object 'k' not found
```

**How do I make the changing variable *k* recognized in the update function of my loop?**

I assume the issue here is that the update function assumes "k" is a column name in my data.frame and therefore cannot find the object. I want it to view **"k" as a variable, not as a parameter name.**

---

**Update**: I tried using `get('k')` in place of just "k." This works if I move the `update` function outside of my "sincos.chooser" function, but creates the same error as above when used *inside* my function.

---

For those that want to see my data & model:

**Original model:**

```
gls(GDD ~ year + pdo, data = dat)
```

**Format of my data:**

```
> dat
    year month   temp.avg   ppt.avg       GDD   pdo  order.ID
1   1922     1  0.4935484 0.3535484  14.40737 -0.45         1
2   1923     2  4.3892857 0.4542857  56.03017 -1.51         2
3   1924     3  7.3032258 0.5435484 106.49244 -1.76         3
4   1925     4 12.8533333 0.2583333 239.07739 -1.71         4
5   1926     5 19.7903226 0.4667742 458.50000 -1.61         5
6   1927     6 24.2766667 0.3146667 578.30000 -1.11         6
```

Comment: does it work with `as.formula` in the update call?

Comment: @KarstenW. this does not work. I get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a neater (or at least more generally applicable) way to do this: use `substitute()`

```
sincos.update <- update(mod3, substitute(.~. + I(cos(2*pi/i*(Plot))) + I(sin(2*pi/i*(Plot))),list(i = as.numeric(k))))
```

Or, in context to the question:

```
sincos.chooser <- function(mod,min,max) {
  my.aic.sincos <- matrix(NA, ncol=2, nrow=max)
  for(k in c(min:max)) { 

    sincos.update <- update(mod3, 
      substitute(
        .~. + I(cos(2*pi/i*(Plot))) + I(sin(2*pi/i*(Plot))),
        list(i = as.numeric(k))
      )
    )

    my.aic.sincos[k,] <- c(k,AIC(sincos.update))
  }
  my.aic.sincos
}
```

This approach also **works well when you try to recursively add variables** (as column names from a data.frame) **to a model**:

```
#Set-up Data
  dat <- data.frame(Id = rep(1:5,3), X = runif(15), Y = runif(15), Var1 = runif(15), Var2 = runif(15))
  varnames <- names(dat)

#Use substitute() in function:    
  lapply(varnames[grep('Var',varnames)], function(x) 
    lm( substitute(Y ~ X + i, list(i = as.name(x))), data = dat)
  )
```

Comment: See another example of this approach [here](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/codefragments/looping_strings/)

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be the neatest way to make this work, but it *is* a solution:

Use `formula` *and* `paste0`:

```
sincos.update <- update(mod, formula(paste0('.~. + I(cos(2*pi/',k,'*(order.ID))) + I(sin(2*pi/',k,'*(order.ID)))')))
```

Comment: I encourage better answers please!